# Disable ssl in apache on port 443

Tags: apache, node.js, ssl, https

I am running a NodeJS app on apache and using mod_proxy to forward requests on 443 to the nodeJS app.

This works fine on port 80, but when I try to set it up for port 443, I get the following error in apache:

```
[error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
```

It appears that this error is caused because I am trying to listen on port 443 in apache but not providing an ssl certificate... but I dont need to as my NodeJS app is performing the SSL.

How can I tell apache to ignore this error?

Comment: You really shouldn't let your node app handle SSL if you put a real webserver in front of it. Besides that, consider using something more lightweight than apache.

Comment: This is a dev box and I need apache to handle multiple routes to different node apps.  On the production box, there is no webserver infront of the the Node app.

Comment: Why don't you just directly access `https://localhost:whateverportnodeuses`?

Comment: This is the alternative, but I would rather access it on port 443

Comment: You need to provide the relevant section of your Apache conf file. For example, I have "SSLProxyEngine on" set & I do provide the certs but then Apache was already handling SSL directly for me before I started using Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying cannot work. A client connecting to port 443 will speak HTTPS/SSL - so the application that handles the connection needs to use SSL for connections on that port.

Comment: The Node app **is** configured for SSL

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you put apache in front of it apache is handling the connection and thus needs to handle SSL. Otherwise it cannot even read the headers of the request (which it needs to forward it to the correct app).

Comment: Not sure that is correct.  All apache needs to know is to forward all requests on port 443 to localhost port xxx (nodejs port).

Comment: This would mean apache is used as a forward proxy, i.e. the browser sends `HTTP CONNECT` requests to it.